# CherryPy terminates session after $window.location.href

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, cherrypy

For a Django 1.8 app with Angular.js & Django Rest Framework I'm using [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org) server to serve the app over WSGI.

For this purpose I'm basically reusing [this code](https://gist.github.com/nigma/4349257), which works fine, until I use the following angular.js command in one of my *.js files:

```
url = patientDetailView + response.data.id + '/';   
$window.location.href=url;
```

The view this link is pointing to requires (like other views as well) the user to be logged in(authenticated). However, although the user has been already logged in after `$window.location.href=url` django redirects to the login screen where the user needs to log-in again! My guess is that this may be due to the session being terminated (?). I don't see this problem while running the django dev server (`./manage.py runserver`)

Anybody can point me to why this is happening and how to fix that? I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: Why do you think django redirects user? What about auth checks in Angular?

Comment: Actually I don't know if this is Django or Angular. The funny thing is that it only happens the first time I open this view. Once I log-in again I can open this view several times and do not get logged-out again... :-/ Any suggestions where and how to dig for the answer?

Comment: It's probably some HTTP Interceptor in Angular, which is checking whether the user has been authenticated.